# ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'smart

Tags: solana, nft, scandir, enoent

PS C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master> ts-node C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet
-k C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\devnet.json -cp C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\config smart contract.json C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\assets

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'smart'
at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1405:3)
at Argument.parseArg (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v2-cli.ts:97:17)
at myParseArg (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1095:34)
at C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1127:19
at Array.forEach ()
at Command._processArguments (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1110:16)
at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1230:12)
at Command._dispatchSubcommand (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1057:25)
at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1200:19)
at Command.parse (C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:889:10) {
errno: -4058,
syscall: 'scandir',
code: 'ENOENT',
path: 'smart'
}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsIwu.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a pathing issue, and its caused because your config file its called `config smart contract.json` you should never use spaces on a file because will cause this behavior. You should change ur config name to something like `config_smart_contract.json` (remove the spaces) and the ts-node call should be (following the new name that I sugested):

`ts-node C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\src\candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload -e devnet -k C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\devnet.json -cp C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\js\packages\cli\config_smart_contract.json C:\Users\ahmad\Desktop\nft\metaplex-master\assets`